# How to sort an array of N elements where each integer belongs to the set {1,2,3,,,k} by using an oracle that answers in yes and no?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

An array has n elements and each element is an integer from the set {1,2,3,,,,k}. There is an oracle that answers anything about the array in yes or no. You only have access to the oracle and not the array. Show that the array can sorted by at most O(klog(n)) queries.

Comment: Define "anything about the array". What if I ask "how many elements in the array have the value 1?"? Will it answer yes, or will it answer no?

Comment: When *sorting* the array we should *change* it (say, swap items); how can we do it if we have no access to the array, but to oracle which can only *answer* questions?

Comment: Do you know what `k` is at the start of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know all of the possible values in the array, it suffices to find the frequency of each possible value. Then output the correct number of 1's, the correct number of 2's, etc.

You can achieve this in `Theta(k log n)` queries, all of the form:

- "Is the frequency of element `x` greater than `c`?"

This amounts to doing a binary search for each of the `k` frequencies. Since the frequency of each element is an integer in `[0, n]`, you can do this binary search with at most `log_2(n+1)+1` queries.